# Cannot run with sound null safety, because the following dependencies [build\windows\flutter\flutter_assemble.vcxproj]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have shifted my entire code to latest dart version 2.15.1. Now I am trying to run the code and it is giving this error.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vmAL.png)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vmAL.png)

Why I am getting this error. Anyone please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because some of your `dependencies` that you are using in your project doesn't support `null-safety` or `Your project` itself doesn't support null-safety but using `dependencies` that supports `null-safety`. To get rid of this problem you can try `upgrading` the `dependency` that is causing the error and if there's no update available for that plugin that run your project using below command :

To `Run`

```
flutter run --no-sound-null-safety
```

To `Build`

```
flutter build apk --release --no-sound-null-safety
```

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, it is not mentioning any package by name with non null-safety feature. Also it is giving some error for VS.

Comment: which version of dart you are using?

Comment: Dart version is 2.15.1

Comment: Have to tried the above commands ?

Comment: If all of my plugins/dependencies are null-safety supported then is there a chance that my project it self is not null-safety supported?

Comment: In general it should not happen then.

Comment: Could you please make me clear your statement "Your project itself doesn't support null-safety but using dependencies that supports null-safety"?

Comment: It means if your project is running in non null-safety mode and you are using latest dependencies it happens when you are using Dart SDK below 2.12 but that is not your case

Answer (score 1):

This error comes when your project or package is not supported on **null safety**
when you are trying to run the project its gives you an error which you see in your picture

if you want to run without null safety use this command

`flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`

when you hit this command on your project it should be run if you face any error kindly comment

Comment: How to use this command for running on desktop. Since I am using flutter run -d windows command

Answer (score 1):

in my case i just type the major version avalaible for the dependency and it works!
from
shared_preferences:

to
shared_preferences: ^2.0.16

With the flutter pub update command, it threw me a reference to the shared_preferences dependency and after investigated options I saw this solution and applied it and it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

1. Press Run
2. Edit Configurations
3. Add Additional Run args
4. `--no-sound-null-safety`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this. I tried to build for Windows and got the null-safety error but the output did not say which packages were the problem, it just showed several paths to Visual Studio.

I then tried to build for Chrome and it did list the packages that did not support null-safety. Hope this helps.